# NativeScript + Vue : let User to Select Color Scheme

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, color-scheme

This is my `app.scss` :

```
// Import app variables
@import 'scss/app-variables-light';
@import 'scss/app-variables-dark';

// Import common styles
@import 'scss/app-common';
```

How can I let the user by tapping on a switch button toggles between `Dark` & `Light` themes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [nativescript-themes](https://npm.proplugins.org/-/web/detail/@proplugins/nativescript-themes) plugin.

Upon user selecting a theme on your UI, call `applyTheme(...)` with CSS path. If you are using SCSS, make sure you compile it into CSS and bundle it along.

Comment: Thanks alot, is there any method that I can edit app.scss file (to add/remove @import line) instead of using the plugin?

Comment: No, imagine once app is compiled, there will be no SCSS, no CSS files it will be just few big JS files from Webpack, you can't do that then.

Comment: It seems that nativescript-themes plugin is not free anymore! Am I right?

Comment: It's still free but the team is maintaining their own NPM repo.

Comment: I get this error:
```tns plugin add @proplugins/nativescript-themes
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@proplugins%2fnativescript-themes - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@proplugins/nativescript-themes@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.```

Comment: I found this one also: [link](https://therankamateur.co.uk/theme-switching-in-nativescript-a26c6aff7ac5)
but it seems that it is suitable for css not SCSS

Comment: First of all, I'm sorry I was wrong. Pro Plugins are subscription based, you will have to take a monthly or yearly subscription. The [free version on Github](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-themes) should still work. End of the day your Browser / NativeScript application can understand only CSS. SCSS is CSS pre-processor with advanced syntax, end of the day it's compiled into CSS only.

Comment: since it does not work as a npm package anymore (free version I mean) , do u know any other plugin? or what do you think about the link I mentioned above? I know the difference between (s)css , I just want find a practical - simple - free way to shift between themes that originally written in scss, right now NativeScript take care of converting them to the css, I am looking for a way to let it know which file should be complied as the css core.

Comment: You mean, you want to change the theme at compile time not at runtime?

Comment: it would nice if it can changes it also in runtime, but it would be handy too if user can select DEFAULT theme and the app reloads and apply the theme.

Comment: Then the plugin is the solution, you may have to adjust your build setup to copy complied CSS files into your bundle. You may also follow the logic from the blog you linked, but the API have changed you will have to adjust the code accordingly.